# Android - FloatingActionButton on Other theme

Tags: android, android-appcompat, floating-action-button

I have to implement FloatingActionButton in my company's Android Application. 
The problem is, the app is pre-style with Holo theme. When I ran the app, it crashed, the error is

```
"java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The style on this component requires your app theme to be Theme.AppCompat".
```

So, the question is: Is there a way to implement FloatingActionButton without AppCompat theme.

Answer (score 0):

The FAB is built into the new Design Compat library - which will work on devices as early as API 7. You will need to include it as a dependency to use it (and shouldn't hesitate to do so).

If you want to avoid using a library (or any external code) you will need to draw the FAB yourself (using a Shape Drawable).

Bottom line, using the Design Compat lib is the preferred method for supporting a FAB, and you should use it. The Design Compat lib IS the "pure/Material API21 stuff".

There is NOT a FAB implementation implemented for any API other then the one in the Design support lib. You have to include the lib, or implement the code entirely yourself.

The Design lib has a dependency on AppCompat, so if you are planning on using the native fab, you will also need to include the dependency for AppCompat.

"Note that as the Design library depends on the Support v4 and AppCompat Support Libraries, those will be included automatically when you add the Design library dependency."

Comment: To be clear. All library included. I found my problem with theme only. In the styles.xml file.

<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
This Theme works, ofcouse

This theme, the one my company app using, not work

style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">